# Firebase onSnapshot realtime with react and redux - Dispatching too many actions concern

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux

I have this react-app which displays a table with a lot of data.

And i need to know when a row of the table gets removed from firebase, but i need to do that realtime and save that data in a reducer dispatching an action so i can access that data in the rest of the app.

**And I did it with an useEffect**

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
            config(terminal!),
            (snapshot) => {
                // let addedData: any[] = [];
                let deletedData: any[] = [];

                snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
                    if (change.type === 'removed') {
                        deletedData = [...deletedData, change.doc.data()];
                    }
                });

                if (deletedData.length > 0) {
                    dispatch(realtimePickups(deletedData, 'removed'));
                }
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            },
        );

        return () => unsubscribe();
    }, []);
```

So, everytime something gets removed, i would dispatch an action, my problem is, is this a good way of doing this ?¿ Would i have performance problems ?¿ Would there be a problem if i dispatch like 50 actions if for some reason 50 rows get removed ?¿

If this is not the best way to do it, would you help me to improve my code.

Comment: Take a look at Virtualized Rows react table: https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/virtualized-rows

Comment: Probably i didn't write the question properly, but my problem is not about the table, is about dispatching multiple actions to redux to save the data, since it is realtime

Comment: Why you store all `deletedData` and after dispach ? You can dispach any changes. You store 2 equal arrays in redux state and in component.

Comment: I need that data in my store, to let know the rest of the app "yo, something has been deleted"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
dispatch(realtimePickups(deletedData, 'removed'));
```

Can cause too many renders depending on the volume of firebase subscription calls. This also depends on two more factors:

1. Is the deleted data used in a component and is mounted in DOM?
2. Are you using an immutable data store?

I recommend a different variation:

1. Install [use-debounce](https://github.com/xnimorz/use-debounce). It has a `useDebouncedCallback` hook which we'll need to use.
2. Then:

```
import { useDebouncedCallback } from 'use-debounce';

let deletedData: any[] = [];

const MyComponent = () => {
  // Debounce massive updates by 1second
  const deletedDataDispatch = useDebouncedCallback((data) => {  
    dispatch(data)
    deletedData = []
  }, 1000);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
      config(terminal!),
      (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
          if (change.type === 'removed') {
            deletedData = [...deletedData, change.doc.data()];
          }
        });

        if (deletedData.length > 0) {
          deletedDataDispatch(realtimePickups(deletedData, 'removed'));
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [])
}
```

Comment: I already have that library installed, it has worked pretty great for my project so far, and i was thinking about this, but didn't know if it was a good option, thanks for the validation man. And also, i think that maybe instead of 1000 ms, i should put at least 2000 ms